# how to update row by row values to table pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have problem with updating values into table after some operations in pl/sql block, but i don't know how to put those values back to SQL table.

Declare block isn't necessary i guess, but im throwing all code i use

```
t_procent:=t_ud_c/c_faktura;
```

i want to put upper value into transactions table into "procent_alokacji" column row by row in that FOR loop, but i don't know why i cant do this like this. How to do that?

```
Declare
type table_products is table of products.unit_duration_calculation%type;
t_products table_products:= table_products();
type table_clients is table of clients.faktura_suma_cj%type;
t_clients table_clients:= table_clients();
CURSOR c_clients is
       Select id_c, faktura_suma_cj, howmuchagreements from clients;
c_id clients.id_c%type;
c_faktura clients.faktura_suma_cj%type;
c_howmuch clients.howmuchagreements%type;
CURSOR c_products is
       select id_p, unit_duration_calculation from products;
p_id products.id_p%type;
p_durat products.unit_duration_calculation%type;
CURSOR c_transactions is
       Select id_t, id_c, id_p, ud_c, procent_alokacji from transactions;
t_id_t transactions.id_t%type;
t_id_c transactions.id_c%type;
t_id_p transactions.id_p%type;
t_ud_c transactions.ud_c%type;
t_procent transactions.procent_alokacji%type;
counter_clients number:=1;
sum_products number:=1;
BEGIN
       open c_clients;
       open c_products;
       open c_transactions;
       fetch c_clients into c_id, c_faktura, c_howmuch;
       fetch c_products into p_id, p_durat;

       FOR i in 1 .. totalTransactions() loop
         fetch c_transactions into t_id_t, t_id_c, t_id_p,t_ud_c, t_procent;
         if counter_clients!=t_id_c Then
           counter_clients:= counter_clients+1;
           fetch c_clients into c_id, c_faktura, c_howmuch;
         end if;
         t_procent:=t_ud_c/c_faktura;
       end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you want it row by row (which is in general the slowest way of doing it)? I assume you can perform the changes in a single UPDATE statement. What is `totalTransactions`?

Comment: If you are trying to update the value of a column in multiple rows of a table based on results from other tables, then you would be far better off doing it in a single UPDATE or MERGE statement, rather than using this very procedural (row-by-row aka slow-by-slow) way. If you need help writing this single DML statement, please edit your question to include some sample data for all your tables along with the expected output you're expecting to see.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit totalTransactions make something like this

`create or replace function totalTransactions
Return number is
       total number(2):=0;
Begin
  Select Count(*) into total from transactions;
  return total;
  end;
`

@Boneist i making it in that way because that way i understan, i mean i need to use SQL or PL/SQL, but when i make SQL complex modificators (like `select`, `update` etc.) i always have errors, even if i make something almost the same like previous i always have errors, so at all i want to make it in pl sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update the table `TRANSACTIONS` with the calculated value `t_procent`. I believe you want to add the following statement after the calculation of `t_procent`:

```
UPDATE TRANSACTIONS
  SET PROCENT_ALOKACJI = t_procent
  WHERE ID_T = t_id_t;
```

Without a full description of the `TRANSACTIONS` table I can't be certain, but it appears that `TRANSACTIONS.ID_T` might be the primary key on the `TRANSACTION` table. If this is not correct feel free to substitute the correct column or columns.

Best of luck.